# Call pie menu in holding state

Tags: python, interface

so here is what i want to do:

holding state = when you hold the key when calling vie keymap
tapping state = when you tap the key when calling vie keymap

call a pie menu from another pie menu set the Confirm Threshold(PreferencesView.pie_menu_confirm) to lets say 20 have the pie menu in the holding state then after the second pie is called reset the Confirm Threshold back to the previous value.
setting the Confirm Threshold is not the problem i have kind of figured that out but when i call a pie menu from another pie menu im in the tapping state unless i call it with the Confirm Threshold already enabled but thats not what i want.